# Como conseguir mediante el puslar un boton hacer aparecer un rectangulo( otro controlador) en WPF de Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy intentando realizar una operación que se trata de una vez que hago click en un botón aparezca otro controlador(rectángulo) y cuando vuelvo a pulsar que desapareczca, pero de momento no me hace ni caso , que podría ser?
dejo mi código aquí abajo:

```
 private void Barrera_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Barrera.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    private void ActivaBarrera_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ActivaBarrera.IsEnabled)
        {
            Barrera.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            Barrera.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
```

Comment: _de momento no me hace ni caso_ eso que significa? No se pone visible nunca? No se oculta despues? Por que preguntas si `ActivaBarrera.IsEnabled`? No sería `ActivaBarrera.Visibility==Visibility.Hidden`?

Comment: el botón no realiza lo que se supone que tiene que hacer, pero acabo de darle al coco un poco mas y me ha salido, aquí a la mínima si no pones el evento adecuado no lo entiende, el visual es muy sensible a esto por lo que veo, voy a dejar una respuesta para otros que les surgen esta duda ya que no he visto ningún post sobre esto en concreto xD

Comment: _el visual es muy sensible a esto_ no,el visual hace lo que tu le dices. Si el evento donde pones tu código no es el correcto, obviamente no te va a funcionar :)

Comment: bueno ya, pero digo que es sensible ya que no te da error si lo pones en otro evento, ósea lo admite aunque no lo haga, a eso me refiero :)

Answer (score 0):

Después de darle un poco mas la coco, he encontrado una solución no es la mejor puede ser pero funciona, aquí dejo el código :

```
private void Barrera_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Barrera.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}

private void ActivaBarrera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ActivaBarrera.IsInitialized)
    {
        Barrera.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }         
}

private void DesactivarBarreraImaginaria_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (DesactivarBarreraImaginaria.IsInitialized)
    {
        Barrera.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```